# cargar imágenes que están en el mismo servidor, pero en distinto espacio web

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

A ver si me puedo explicar bien.

Tengo 2 páginas alojadas en el mismo hosting, la página principal, que es la página que verá el público (carpeta física: X:/.../.../ppal/wwwroot) y la página de configuración que la manejará un administrador (carpeta física: X:/.../.../cfg/wwwroot).

Desde la página cfg se suben imágenes que las guardo en la carpeta X:/.../.../ppal/wwwroot/imgs (eso lo hago utilizando WebRootPath:

**string rutaRaiz = _env.WebRootPath.Substring(0, _env.WebRootPath.IndexOf("ppal") + 4) + @"\wwwroot";**
nota: + 4 es para que coja los 4 caracteres de ppal.

rutaRaiz es la ruta física de la página ppal **X:/.../.../ppal/wwwroot**

La primera parte ya funciona, subo las imágenes desde la página cfg y las guardo en la carpeta X:/.../.../ppal/wwwroot/imgs:

**string file = Path.Combine(rutaRaiz, "imgs", nomArch + ".jpg");**

Lo siguiente que tengo que hacer es mostrar en la página cfg esas imágenes que se han guardado en la ruta física de ppal. Así no tengo que guardar 2 veces las imágenes tanto en cfg como en ppal.

¿Alguna idea de cómo poner la ruta de ppal en el src de una etiqueta img en la página cfg?

Este es el código javascript en la página cfg que carga la imagen correspondiente:

**$("#img").attr('src', 'imgs//' + id + '.jpg');**

Es aquí donde tengo que indicar el archivo de imagen que se va a mostrar, por ejemplo X:/.../.../ppal/wwwroot/imgs/2.jpg.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento lo he solucionado de esta manera:

**let imgUrl = 'https://ppal.com/imgs/' + id + '.jpg';**

**$("#img").attr('src', imgUrl);**

Pero no me parece la forma más idónea.

Otra forma que se me ocurre es mediante api:
Crear una función de api que devuelva un tipo Image.
¿Cómo pondría en el src la imagen devuelta?

¿Más ideas?

Gracias